# What is default "Authentication Required" response (307)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

My software consumes SOAP web service. when calling one of the methods within the WSDL, it returned

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Authentication Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Authentication Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Authentication Required" response (307) -->
</BODY>
```

The service which I've developed is .NET SOAP web service ran on IIS, windows server 2016, and it doesn't require any credentials. Any idea what could be the reason that i've got this message ?

Comment: It seems you were redirected by some proxy because you didn't provide authentication with the call. What web service are you calling? You say "My Service". Did you write this? Where is it deployed? You need to provide more details.

Comment: @Bogdan, I just updated my question. The web service is .Net SOAP hosted on IIS in windows server 2016.

Comment: Check your IIS authentication settings for the website

Comment: already checked, no authentication required 
@Charlieface

Comment: Meaning it is marked as enabled for "Anonymous Authentication"?

Comment: Yes @Charlieface

Answer (score 0):

The `307` Temporary Redirect message represents an HTTP response status code which indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to another URI.

This status code was added to the HTTP standard in HTTP 1.1 (as detailed in the RFC2616 specification document that establishes the standards for that version of HTTP). It's indicated in the RFC that “since the redirection may be altered on occasion, the client should continue to use the Request-URI for future requests.”

More about this Status code - https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/307-temporary-redirect